# Overflow:hidden CSS not working in Prince XML

Tags: html-to-pdf, princexml

I have description that is overflow:hidden in HTML page since it was overflowing the data in PDF to next page.

I see the data hidden after an extent in HTML but on generation of PDF the whole description comes up till the next page. This is with Prince XML 13.3. This issue is in my local while in higher environments the data is truncated correctly but a blank page is introduced in PDF.

I read about the overflow: hidden css works for some builds of Prince tried all of them but none seems to be working. Any suggestions would be a great help!!.

Comment: Can you post your code so we can look at it?

Comment: Hey James, thank you for a quick response. I could resolve the issue by limiting the whole div to overflow:hidden rather than a section of it within the div.